# How to do Multiple conditional execution of stage using 'when' in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to convert Scripted pipelines into Declarative Pipeline.

Here is a
**Pipeline:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '',
               description: '',
               name : 'BRANCH_NAME')
        choice (
                choices: 'DEBUG\nRELEASE\nTEST',
                description: '',
                name : 'BUILD_TYPE')
    } 
    stages {
        stage('Release build') {
           when {
               expression {params.BRANCH_NAME == "master"}
               expression {params.BUILD_TYPE == 'RELEASE'}
            }
            steps {
                echo "Executing Release\n"
            }
        } //stage
    } //stages
} // pipeline
```

Intension is that all the parameter values need to be compared under `when` and only then I wanted executed a stage.

In scripted pipeline you can use && like in snippet below.

```
stage('Release build') {
    if ((responses.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') && 
       (responses.BUILD_TYPE == 'RELEASE')) {
         echo "Executing Release\n"
    }
}
```

How to get collective return from `expression` in declarative pipeline?

Comment: Are you looking for `allOf { ... }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be like

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '',
               description: '',
               name : 'BRANCH_NAME')
        choice (
                choices: 'DEBUG\nRELEASE\nTEST',
                description: '',
                name : 'BUILD_TYPE')
    } 
    stages {
        stage('Release build') {
           when {
               allOf {
                    expression {params.BRANCH_NAME == "master"};
                    expression {params.BUILD_TYPE == 'RELEASE'}
               }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Executing Release\n"
            }
        } //stage
    } //stages
} // pipeline
```

you can find other dsl support inside `when` [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)